# How to make the marker to default after click using mapbox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have markers, if i click on one marker it gets enlarged, and if i click on other marker both the markers are enlarged. But i want the latest clicked marker to be enlarged and rest to be default. Kindly help.

Ts:

```
map.on("click", "points" + i, e => {
      this.showStory = true;
      this.id = undefined;
      this.mapData = e.features[0].properties
      console.log(this.mapData.field[0]);
      map.setPaintProperty(e.features[0].layer.id, 'circle-radius', 20); 
    });
```

Please anyone help.

Code is in this plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/6F5Ax2PXwJb74vN0KCU1?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As, you have taken different coordinates, change the click logic of coordinartes to,

```
map.on("click", "points" + i, e => {
      console.log(e)
      this.id = undefined;
      this.mapData = e.features[0].properties
      console.log(this.mapData.field);
      for(var i=0; i< coOrdinates.length; i++) {
        map.setPaintProperty('points'+i, 'circle-radius', 15); 
      }
      map.setPaintProperty(e.features[0].layer.id, 'circle-radius', 20); 
    });
```

[**Here is the updated plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mFCI4NtTRtxAvBNtnrqy?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you soo much this was what i was searching for